# How to migrate from activeMQ to ibmMQ in camelContext configuration?

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, ibm-mq

I am currently using AciveMQ for routing purpose. But now i need to migrate to ibmMq. Here is my camelContext.xml configuration for AciveMq. Please help me with ibmMq config.. 
Thanks in advance.

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory"
          class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="pooledConnectionFactory"
          class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
        <property name="maxConnections" value="8"/>
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsConfig"
          class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10"/>
    </bean>
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <bean id="activemq"
          class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
        <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig"/>
    </bean>

<route id="*****">
            <from uri="+++++++++" />
            <choice>
                    <to uri="activemq:queue:**********"/>
                            </choice>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

Can anybody help me change all my configuration with respective to IBMmq
I am new to IBMmq :(

Comment: What problem have run into switching to IBM WMQ connection factories and Camel JMS component?

Comment: Its requirement changes. We need to use IBM mq now. Help me with configuration changes if i use IBM mq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I managed to configure with ibm mq :)

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
          brokerName="${broker-name}"
          dataDirectory="${data}"
          start="false">
    ...
  </broker>
  ...
  <!-- Configure IBM WebSphere MQ connection factory -->
  <bean id="weblogicConnectionFactory"
        class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="transportType" value="1"/>
    <property name="hostName" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="port" value="1414"/>
    <property name="queueManager" value="QM_TEST"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="weblogicConfig" 
        class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="weblogicConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="weblogic" 
        class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="weblogicConfig"/>
  </bean>
```

Successfully :)

Comment: thanks! but I think you only needed the first bean ConnectionFactory, because this is what is required by camel to define the jms. you question was not related to weblogic. nevertheless, your answer was useful to me